# Why on my table PrimeFaces the filter does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to add a filter to my table PrimeFaces but does not work with all possible modifications. I followed all the recommendations of fellow StackOverflow and still not working. No exceptions or errors on my tomcat or Javascript / jQuery. I'm using Primefaces javax.faces 5.1 and 2.2.9. I leave my part of the code to be helped on me please. Regards:

```
<div class="contenido_datatable">
  <h:form id="dtClientes" style="vertical-align: middle !important;">
    <p:dataTable 
        id="clientesDT" 
        var="cliente" 
        rows="11"
        value="#{dtFrmClientes.clientesLazy}" 
        paginator="true"
        selectionMode="single" 
        sortBy="#{cliente.cif}" 
        lazy="true" 
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink}                                                       {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks}{NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
        currentPageReportTemplate="Total: {totalRecords}. Página {currentPage} de {totalPages}" 
        selection="#{dtFrmClientes.clienteSeleccionado}" 
        rowKey="#{cliente.id_cliente}"
        emptyMessage="No existen registros"
        widgetVar="clienteFilt">
        <p:ajax event="filter"></p:ajax>
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{dtFrmClientes.onRowSelect}" update=":formularioClientes" />
        <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{dtFrmClientes.onRowUnselect}" update=":formularioClientes" />

        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:inputText 
                    styleClass="cuadroBusq" 
                    id="globalFilter" 
                    maxlength="10" 
                    onkeyup="PF('clienteFilt').filter()" 
                    placeholder="Buscar..">
            </p:inputText>
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="filter" onkeyup="PF('clienteFilt').filter()" update=":dtClientes:clientesDT"></f:facet>

        <p:column headerText="CIF" id="cif" widht="100px;" sortBy="#{cliente.cif}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{cliente.cif}" filterStyle="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
            <h:outputText value="#{cliente.cif}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Nombre/Razón Social" sortBy="#{cliente.nombre}" filterMatchMode="contains" width="165px;" filterBy="#{cliente.nombre}" filterStyle="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
                <h:outputText value="#{cliente.nombre}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Teléfono" sortBy="#{cliente.telefono}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{cliente.telefono}" filterStyle="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
                <h:outputText value="#{cliente.telefono}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Fecha Alta" sortBy="#{cliente.fecha_alta}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="text-align: center;" filterBy="#{cliente.fecha_alta}" filterStyle="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
                <h:outputText value="#{cliente.fecha_alta2}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Fecha Baja" sortBy="#{cliente.fecha_baja}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="text-align:center;" filterBy="#{cliente.fecha_baja}" filterStyle="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
                <h:outputText value="#{cliente.fecha_baja2}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column styleClass="columnaOpciones">
            <p:commandLink 
                rendered="#{cliente.id_cliente != 0}" 
                styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash imagenBorrarLista" 
                update=":formConfirm:cCliente" 
                oncomplete="PF('cCliente').show();" 
                ajax="true" 
                immediate="true" 
                action="#{dtFrmClientes.onRowSelect2}">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{cliente.id_cliente}" target="#{dtFrmClientes.id_cliente}" />      
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{cliente.nombre}" target="#{dtFrmClientes.ds_cliente}" />          
            </p:commandLink>        
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
  </h:form>
</div>
```

Comment: But, the filteredValue is necesary for the global filter? Because I've seen examples where they had not this property. Thankss!

Comment: Ok it's already corrected. I forgot to pass the filter to lazy method.  


public List<RCliente> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, org.primefaces.model.SortOrder sortOrder, java.util.Map<String, Object> filters)

Thank you very much!!